# Python substituting dynamic variables in arguments

Tags: python, variables, arguments

My chat script requires four args to execute:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import argparse
import xmpp

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-c', dest='contact', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-u', dest='username', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-p', dest='password', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-m', dest='message', required=False, default='')
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)

    if (args.message == '') and not sys.stdin.isatty():
        for line in sys.stdin:
            args.message = args.message + line

    jid = xmpp.protocol.JID(args.username)
    jabber = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(), debug=[])
    jabber.connect(server=(jid.getDomain(), 5222) )
    jabber.auth(jid.getNode(), args.password)

    jabber.send(xmpp.Message(args.contact, args.message.strip()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I am calling this chat.py from another python script called listen.py as so:

```
...
import chat
...
chat.main(['-c', 'user@server.com', '-u', 'fromme@server.com', '-p', 'password', '-m', 'Yo Yo Yo Wassup'])
...
```

Here is my problem, I have been trying to use variables in my arguments. So if I have the following:

```
from = "fromme@server.com"
to = "toyou@server.com"
pass = "password"
message = "Yo Yo Yo Wassup"
```

I want to use these variables in the chat.main as so:

```
chat.main(['-c', '%s', '-u', '%s', '-p', '%s', '-m', '%s' & (from,to,pass,message)])
```

Problem is that I get a mixture of errors such as "String expected, tuple found" or "not all converted to string"

What am I doing wrong?  I have been using this type of format in previous python lines, but were not used in arguments.

The reason is that these variables will be dynamic later and be pulled from a database instead.

Comment: Did you try ```chat.main(['-c', to, '-u', from, '-p', pass, '-m', message])```?

Comment: Got to be kidding me. The only easiest one on Earth that I did not try. Thanks a lot guy.  This works great!